# iPhone marks first unread e-mail as read

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app

I believe this problem started with iOS 9. My iPhone is connected to an IMAP account and used to correctly maintain unread status. Now it is common for - especially but perhaps not exclusively - the first unread e-mail to lose its unread status.

I mark the message as unread and it shows the unread status, the unread count increases, it sync with the server (status line spinner runs and stops). Later on, sometimes very shortly (seconds) afterwards, the unread count has gone down again and the message has lost its status. This seems to happen whether the message view, the unread view, inbox view or all inboxes view is the view that is left open. The message is not open on another device.

My Google skills are not turning up much for this. Any ideas?

Comment: It's possible that this is prevented if there is a newer unread message that has never been opened. I don't believe I've seen it happen in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in iOS 10 (there was a moderately large update of Mail.app).

Comment: We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can really add in this case. It was broken for several major releases, now it's fixed. I could never find a ticket for it.